# how to stop a quickfix-initiator

Tags: c++, quickfix

I am running a fix-initiator application, coded in c++ on Solaris X86 platform.
To start and stop the application on a regular base I use a shell-script wrapper and cron which, for stop, does a kill on the pid of the application.
I wonder whether there is a more elegant and "professional" way to stop the innitiator, because kill immediately shuts down the complete process without any proper logout on the fix-sessions, disconnects on the sockets, deleting file-handles, etc..

Can you please advice or give an example on how to handle the SIGINT inside the fix-application?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), this is what you actually need. An example how to use you find [here](https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/sigaction) - sure, C, but applicable in C++ as well...

If you discover [signal](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) being easier to handle (truth...): Well, avoid it (see the link...).

Be aware that kill by default sends `SIGTERM`, so this is what you actually should catch...

Be aware, too, that from with signal handlers, you only are allowed to use async-safe functions! A list of is contained at [here](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)

I assume your programme is running within some loop. To avoid problems with non-async-safe functions, you might consider just resetting a loop condition in the signal handler and let the rest handle the main thread again (breaking from the loop and cleaning up afterwards).

If you rely on blocking IO, though, you might introduce a call to [select](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [poll](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) (if not yet done so anyway), checking the IO handles especially before read. You might add an additional file descriptor you activate from the signal handler then to be able to break select/poll prematurely.

Such an additional file handler you can get with [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), which is, however, linux specific, or in a more portable way by opening a pipe and writing to it from within the signal handler.